# enums in different classes are incompatible?

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

So I'm making a game and I have a Player class that has an enum for which direction the player is currently facing, up, left, etc.

```
Player.h
#include "Fireball.h"
class Player
{
   // Some stuff
   Fireball fireballs;
   void update();

   private:
   enum direction {up, left, down, right, upLeft, upRight, downLeft, downRight} playerDir;
};
```

I also have a Spell class that I will derive specific spells from, Fireball for instance. The Spell class has an enum that is the same as the one in the Player class, as I want to be able to pass the current direction of the player as a parameter when I update the instance of the spell, and move the spell in that direction.

```
Spell.h
class Spell
{
// Some stuff

protected:
   enum direction {up, left, down, right, upLeft, upRight, downLeft, downRight};
};
```

.

```
Fireball.h
#include "Spell.h"
class Fireball : public Spell
{
public:
   void updateFireballs(direction fireballDir);
};
```

.

```
Player.cpp
#include "Player.h"

void Player::update()
{
   fireballs.updateFireballs(playerDir);
}
```

When I try and pass playerDir as a parameter to the updateFireballs function, it complains that it cannot convert 'Player::direction' to 'Spell::direction'.

How do I pass an enum from a different class as a parameter of a function in a different class?

Comment: Why do you want to define separate enumerations in both classes, especially if you want to use them interchangeably? It would make more sense to have a common definition outside both classes.

Comment: Even if you define `direction` outside class Player, inside you can still say `using direction = ::direction;` to make `Player::direction` a synonym of the global `direction`. But perhaps you have something like a `class Map` - directions typically belong to maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each enumeration is its own type. When you define two enumerations in different classes you define two types. They may have the same member names, but they are unrelated.

When you need a common enumeration define one. If you find that this enumeration would have a name clash you should define a kind of "container" for it. This can be a namespace or a base class for your classes `Player` and `Spell`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the enum class twice in unrelated classes. You can define it outside the classes. If you still want it under Spell class, make it public so other classes can see it.

```
class Spell
{
public:
    enum Direction {up, left, down, right, upLeft, upRight, downLeft, downRight};
};

class Fireball : public Spell
{
public:
    void updateFireballs(Spell::Direction fireballDir);
};

class Player
{
    Fireball fireballs;
    void update()
    {
        fireballs.updateFireballs(playerDir);
    }
private:
    Spell::Direction playerDir;
};
```